# Do while loop to check if file exists

Tags: c#, loops

I'm writing a C# program for the company I work for that will launch a PHP script which creates a PDF, and then opens the PDF file.  Right now, I have:

```
// launch the PHP page to generate my pdf report
Process.Start(phpFile);

// wait for the report to exist
Thread.Sleep(waitTime);

// open the report
Process.Start(filePath);
```

Now, I'm not a fan of the whole "`Sleep()` for a specified time in hopes of the file existing when it's done".  So my question is, is it feasible/better to use a `do` loop and say:

```
do
{
    // Do nothing until the file exists 
} while (!File.Exists(filePath));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) ?

Set the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path.aspx) and [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter.aspx) property and subscribe to the [Created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event.

Comment: I like this approach.  But as someone stated in another comment, will this wait until the PDF is fully written, or is it possible it will try to open it before hand?

Comment: Good question ... I think it will raise the event as soon as the file is there.  If that 's the case, then Sean's answer will be the solution.

Comment: I tested using this, and it worked phenomenally. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with using `File.Exists` is that the file may exist prior to it finishing being written by the first process.  I would do something like this instead:

```
// launch the PHP page to generate my pdf report
Process generator = Process.Start(phpFile);

// wait for the report to exist
generator.WaitForExit();

// open the report
Process.Start(filePath);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `FileSystemWatcher` and handle the created event. If you want it to happen synchronously use `FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged` with a timeout

Answer (score 0):

I think is a better aproach to look if the file exists in any way. If you rely on a fixed amount of time it can fail or the process will be waiting more than it needs.

Answer (score 0):

What about waiting for the end of the first process ?

```
Process p = Process.Start(phpFile);
p.WaitForExit();

Process.Start(filePath);
```